# Using a dictionary with aspell and emacs that is not listed by ispell

Tags: emacs, aspell

I am running Emacs 23 and Aspell in a Debian Squeeze system.  I've installed the aspell-hi package and spell checking of Hindi files works fine from the command line. I've set up aspell to replace ispell in emacs using the instructions [here](http://aspell.net/man-html/Using-Aspell-with-other-Applications.html).

However, I can't find any way to make Emacs tell aspell to use the Hindi dictionary.  Hindi does not appear in the list of dictionaries you get when you type M-x ispell-change-dictionary .  If I just type in "hindi" I get "No match found."  If I even try the crude method of saying `(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell -d hi")` in my .emacs, I get an error that no such program is found.

I have searched extensively online but can't find any solution to the question of setting dictionaries in aspell in emacs, other than personal dictionaries and those listed by M-x ispell-change-dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian include automatic way to configure ispell.el for the installed dictionary.

First try to run

```
emacs -q
```

and test with this "bare Emacs" if the hindi dictionary is available

- `C-h v ispell-program-name` to look at the default "ispell" use by Emacs (should be aspell)
- Try to change dictionary to hindi
- you can also `C-h v C-h v ispell-program-name` to see the list of the available dictionary

If you have hindi in the "bare Emacs" then just remove all configuration you made in the .emacs concerning ispell and aspell.

If this fail, add:

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist
     '("hindi"
        "[a-zA-Z]"
        "[^a-zA-Z]"
        "[']"
        nil
        ("-d" "hi")
        nil
        iso-8859-1))
```

to your .emacs

Comment: You're exactly right - it worked fine in bare emacs with `emacs -q`.  I stripped out all my config attempts from .emacs and found that, as you also said, Debian defaults to aspell in emacs and the configuration was automatic.  All is well now, and many thanks